# value from SELECT command is object

Tags: google-app-engine

I am doing a project in google app engine. Python is used in the back end. I have a datastore table "Data" with following attributes,

```
class Data(db.Model):
  url = db.StringProperty
  code = db.StringProperty
  turl = db.StringProperty
```

I used following lines of code to get all values from the table,

```
x = Data.all()
        x = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Data")
        ourl = x.fetch(10)
```

When i print it using the following code,

```
for p in ourl:
          print "%s %s, %s " % (p.url, p.code, p.turl)
```

i got 10 times the following message,

```
<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty'> <class 'google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty'>, <class 'google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty'>
```

I cannot get the real values of url,code and turl. What to do with this code??

Comment: In addition to sahid's (correct) response - the first two lines of your code do exactly the same thing. Delete one of them (your choice as to which).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `class Data` you forgot parenthesis to create instances of property.

```
class Data(db.Model):
  url = db.StringProperty()
  code = db.StringProperty()
  turl = db.StringProperty()
```

Currently your simply copy the class `db.StringProperty` in your attributes defined in your `class Data`